# How to generate a fractal graph of a market in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, fractals

I wish to generate this in python:

http://classes.yale.edu/fractals/RandFrac/Market/TradingTime/Example1/Example1.html

but I'm incredibly stuck and new to this concept. Does anybody know of a library or gist for this?

[image]

Edit:
From what I can understand is that you need to split the fractal in 2 every time. So you have to calculate the y-axis point from the line between the two middle points. Then the two sections need to be formed according to the fractal?

Comment: _"I wish to generate this in python"_. You want to generate a website about fractals? There are a number of interesting web frameworks available. Have you tried Django?

Comment: @Kevin lol, no, obviously not. I'm looking for the recursion function.

Comment: Can you provide a more specific link? What you have now just goes to the front page.

Comment: @Kevin thanks for the info. Stupid iframes, sigh. I've updated the link.

Comment: Not really clear what you are asking. Do you want to generate a somewhat realisitic looking stock market graph? Or do you want to implement this 'price vs. trading time' normalization? Also, is there any input data, or do you just want random graphs?

Comment: @tobias_k Just to generate the market graph using this fractal approach. This same function I can just repeat with implementing the trading time normalization, so don't worry about that.

Comment: please add "Graph" to the title... I saw "Fractal Market" and was like, whaaaaat o_O

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not 100% sure what you are asking, but as I understood from your comments, you want to generate a realistically looking stock market curve using the recursion described in the link.

As far as I understood the description in the linked page and [some of the parent pages](http://classes.yale.edu/fractals/RandFrac/Cartoon/BrownianCartoons/BrownianCartoons.html), it works like this:

1. You are given a start and an end point and a number of turning points in the form *(t<sub>1</sub>, v<sub>1</sub>)*, *(t<sub>2</sub>, v<sub>2</sub>)*, etc., for example `start=(0,0), end=(1,1), turns = [(1/4, 1/2), (3/4, 1/4)]`, where *t<sub>i</sub>* and *v<sub>i</sub>* are fractions between 0 and 1.
2. You determine the actual turning points scaled to that interval between *start* and *end* and calculate the differences between those points, i.e. how far to go from *p<sub>i</sub>* to reach *p<sub>i+1</sub>*.
3. You shuffle those segments to introduce some randomness; when put together, they still cover exactly the same distance, i.e. they connect the original *start* and *end* point.
4. Repeat by recursively calling the function for the different segments between the new points.

Here's some Python code I just put together:

```
from __future__ import division
from random import shuffle

def make_graph(depth, graph, start, end, turns):
    # add points to graph
    graph.add(start)
    graph.add(end)

    if depth > 0:   
        # unpack input values
        fromtime, fromvalue = start
        totime, tovalue = end

        # calcualte differences between points
        diffs = []
        last_time, last_val = fromtime, fromvalue
        for t, v in turns:
            new_time = fromtime + (totime - fromtime) * t
            new_val = fromvalue + (tovalue - fromvalue) * v
            diffs.append((new_time - last_time, new_val - last_val))
            last_time, last_val = new_time, new_val

        # add 'brownian motion' by reordering the segments
        shuffle(diffs)

        # calculate actual intermediate points and recurse
        last = start
        for segment in diffs:
            p = last[0] + segment[0], last[1] + segment[1]
            make_graph(depth - 1, graph, last, p, turns)
            last = p
        make_graph(depth - 1, graph, last, end, turns)

from matplotlib import pyplot
depth = 8
graph = set()
make_graph(depth, graph, (0, 0), (1, 1), [(1/9, 2/3), (5/9, 1/3)])
pyplot.plot(*zip(*sorted(graph)))
pyplot.show()
```

And here some example output:

[image]

Comment: That's very good, and yes, exactly what I'm looking for. One more thing though, `depth = 1` should give `len(graph)` as 4, etc. Would it be possible to use a `set` from the start or should I make `graph` unique afterwards?

Comment: @Tjorriemorrie Good catch, that was not intended. Seems like the points were added multiple times, e.g. (0,0) was added for each smaller and smaller segment starting at (0,0). Alternatively, you could just add the intermediate points (had it like this in my first version), but then you have to treat the first start and end point separately. As suggested, I changed `graph` to be a `set` to avoid this; everything else works just the same.

Comment: Thanks, that's some seriously good python coding right there :) And +1 for making it easy for me to toggle the `shuffle`

Comment: @tobias_k: Could this code be extended to use real datetime values for the x-axis and generate realistic looking fractal OHLC data points?  Would like to try creating a synthesised streaming Bokeh finance plot, could use a fractal generator as the OHLC engine.

Comment: @GoFaster I am no market expert, but I don't see why that should not work. Just replace `0.0` on the x axis with the opening time, `1.0` with the closing time, and interpolate the values in between accordingly.

Comment: @GoFaster: I had the same need. 

The @tobias_k fractal solution is a non-dmimensinalized [0,0]x[1,1] fractal. You can use whatever data that support sum, subtraction and float multiplication as `start` and `end` points.

As none seems to answer this particular point I will post my humble solution using pandas. All the credits for @tobias_k.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar interest and developed a python3 library to do just what you want.

```
pip install fractalmarkets
```

See https://github.com/hyperstripe50/fractal-market-analysis/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0):

Using @tobias_k solution and pandas, we can translate and scale the normalized fractal to a time-based one.

```
import arrow
import pandas as pd
import time

depth = 5
# the "geometry" of fractal
turns = [
        (1 / 9, 0.60),
        (5 / 9, 0.30),
        (8 / 9, 0.70),
    ]

# select start / end time 
t0 = arrow.now().floor("hours")
t1 = t0.shift(days=5)
start = (pd.to_datetime(t0._datetime), 1000)
end = (pd.to_datetime(t1._datetime), 2000)

# create a non-dimensionalized [0,0]x[1,1] Fractal
_start, _end = (0, 0), (1, 1)  
graph = set()
make_graph(depth, graph, _start, _end, turns)
# just check graph length
assert len(graph) == (len(turns) + 1) ** depth + 1

# create a pandas dataframe from the normalized Fractal
df = pd.DataFrame(graph)
df.sort_values(0, inplace=True)
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

# translate to real coordinates
X = pd.DataFrame(
        data=[(start[0].timestamp(), start[1]), (end[0].timestamp(), end[1])]
        ).T
delta = X[1] - X[0]
Y = df.mul(delta) + X[0]
Y[0] = [*map(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, unit="s"), Y[0])]

# now resample and interpolate data according to *grid* size
grid ="min"
Z = Y.set_index(0)
A = Z.resample(grid).mean().interpolate()

# plot both graph to check errors
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ax = Z.plot()
A.plot(ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

showing both graphs:

[image: Both graphs]

and zooming to see interpolation and snap-to-grid differences:

[image]